# SFTP not connecting to remote server

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am trying to connect to a remote SFTP server using PHP. My code works fine when I connect to a local SFTP account but it times out for remote host. I have made sure through FTP client that host information is correct and its connecting fine.

I am using phpseclib library and my three line code is below.

```
require_once("phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php");

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('remote_host_IP');
var_dump($sftp->login('<username>', '<password>'));
```

It returns false (meaning not connected).

**What I have done**

- I have whitelisted script in mod_security just in case its blocking that.
- I have tried same script on my local computer and it connects successfully to remote SFTP.

Any valuable hint please?

Comment: Did you try to transfer the file manually via sftp?

Comment: Yes, I used winSCP on my local computer (windows 7) and it connects and upload/download files successfully. Also, same script connects fine when I run on my local computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help others. You need to make sure TCP_OUT port is open on your remote server to make it work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` before initializing Net_SFTP and then do `$sftp->getLog()` after `$sftp->login()`

That'll provide enough info with which a diagnostic can be made.